# how to open browser in action result?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have a action tresult method and in it i want to open a url in new window or new tab how can i handel it ?

in my code it works not i mean redirect it to member account and do not open my url

```
public ActionResult myactionresult()
    {
         Response.Write("<script language=\"javascript\">");
         Response.Write("window.open('" + "http://www.xxx.com" + ,'_blank')");
         Response.Write("</script>");

       return RedirectToAction("Index", "MembersAccount");
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead :

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult myactionresult()
{
    String jScript = String.Empty;
    jScript = "<script language=\"javascript\">";
    jScript += "window.open('http://www.xxx.com' ,'_blank')";
    jScript += "</script>";

    ViewBag.jScript = jScript;

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "MembersAccount");
}
```

**View :**  *Any where in view's body*

```
@ViewBag.jScript
```

This will fix your problem;

Comment: my redirection must happened in action result in your case any redirection will happened

Comment: @motevallizadeh, do you want to open another window via actionresult and dont want to open that perticular action?

Comment: @ Kundan Singh Chouhan ,yes i vant to open it after it this last line redirect to my action

Comment: @motevallizadeh, did you run this code? I think this is working as expected.